# Connect to MySQL/MariaDB from the command line client with a URI connection string?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Given a URI-style DB connection string:

```
mysql://<user>:<pass>@<host>:<port>/<database>
```

Is there a way to use this string directly with the MySQL command line client without decomposing it into the familiar `mysql -u <user> -h <host> -p ...` format?

I found some discussion of this [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting-using-uri-or-key-value-pairs.html), but the suggested option `--uri` is not present in my client (mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.11.2-MariaDB).

Comment: Use a simple shell script to parse the string and run mysql?

Comment: MariaDB hasn't implemented this option. You can request it [as a task on JIRA](https://jira.mariadb.org). Given the move away from putting passwords on process arguments what is the use case? Easier to remember than command options?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `mysqlsh` (mysql shell) instead of `mysql`.

Use the `--uri=<your connection string>` option.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysqlsh.html#option_mysqlsh_uri